# How to generate random numbers at the tails of an exponential distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to generate random numbers like from `np.random.exponential` but clipped / truncated at values `a,b`. For example, if `a=100`, `b=500` then I want the function to generate random numbers following `e^(-x)` in the range `[100, 500]`.

An inefficient way would be:

```
rands = np.random.exponential(size=10**7)
rands = rands[(rands>a) and (rands<b)]
```

Is there an existing package that can do this for me? Ideally for various distributions, not just exponential.

Comment: You can basically just call ``rand = np.exp(np.random.uniform(low=a, high=b, size=1e7))``. Any reason why you did not implement this function?

Comment: @BatWannaBe oh I totally missed that point. You are right, should have been ``rand = np.random.uniform(low=np.exp(a), high=np.exp(b), size=1e7)``

Answer (score 1):

If we clip the values after using the exponential generator, there are two problems with approach proposed in the question.

- First, we lose values (For example, if we wanted 10**7 values, we might only get 10^6 values)
- Second, `np.random.exponential()` returns values between 0 and 1, so we can't simply use 100 and 500 as the lower and upper bounds. We must scale the generated random numbers before scaling.

I wrote the workaround using exp(uniform). I tested your solution using smaller values of a and b (so that we don't get empty arrays). A timed approach shows this is faster by around 50%

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   

def truncated_exp_OP(a,b, how_many):
    rands = np.random.exponential(size=how_many)
    rands = rands[(rands>a) & (rands<b)]
    return rands


def truncated_exp_NK(a,b, how_many):
    a = -np.log(a)
    b = -np.log(b)
    rands = np.exp(-(np.random.rand(how_many)*(b-a) + a))
    return rands

timeTakenOP = []
for i in range(20):
    startTime = time.time()
    r = truncated_exp_OP(0.001,0.39, 10**7)
    endTime = time.time() 
    timeTakenOP.append(endTime - startTime)
print ("OP solution: ", np.mean(timeTakenOP))
plt.hist(r.flatten(), 300);
plt.show()



timeTakenNK = []
for i in range(20):
    startTime = time.time()
    r = truncated_exp_NK(100,500, 10**7)
    endTime = time.time()
    timeTakenNK.append(endTime - startTime)
print ("NK solution: ", np.mean(timeTakenNK))
plt.hist(r.flatten(), 300);
plt.show()
```

Average run time :

```
OP solution:  0.28491891622543336 vs 
NK solution:  0.1437338709831238
```

The histogram plots of the random numbers are shown below:

OP's approach:

[image]

This approach:

[image]